# How to call a function in modal from parent page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in power portal where I want to execute some code on closing of the modal. I am opening a modal window (it doesn't have an id) and powerportals only allow Bootstrap 3.3.

I have added following code in the parent page:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $(document).on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function(){child.dbSave()});}
```

and it works fine but if I add the same code in the modal(i.e. child window) window it doesn not get executed and modal just closes.

There is function (dbSave()) on the modal that does the save of item in db.

Is there a way I can call dbSave() function from the parent page? I have tried child.dbSave() but it returns a

```
 reference error: dbSave is not defined at HTMLButtonElemen
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of it not working.

Comment: _"There is function (dbSave()) on the modal that does the save of item in db."_ - but the error says there isn't

Comment: @evolutionxbox --issue is when I call $(document).on('click', '[data-dismiss="modal"]', function(){child.dbSave()}) from modal itself it does not get executed, but when I call the same piece of code from parent page(i.e. page that launches the modal)  I get the error that error as parent page cannot see dbSave() function in child window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have bootstrap 3.3 and make modals using bootstrap, there are some events on bootstrap modal that are useful:
[modal events on bootstrap 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events)

you should trigger it like this:

```js
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal',()=>{save()})

function save(){
console.log('fired and saved');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">Launch modal</button>
```